# RISC V Processor

Tags: architecture, risc

I am working on RISC V Processor. I want to know is RV32 and RV32I are same. For RISC V, i am studying Computer Organization and Design, T H E H A R D W A R E S O F T W A R E I N T E R F A C E, SECOND EDITION
David A. Patterson, University of California, Berkeley Book.

I read the mentioned book.